# Replacing placeholder with multiple lines

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a template that looks like:

```
<mydata>
<tag1> 
<tag2> etc.
DATAHERE
</mydata>
```

I want to run a query on a DB and fetch a number of records and place them one below the other in the file at the place where there is the string DATAHERE.

My records are already fetched in mydata.txt. How do i replace the single line of DATAHERE ? I do not want to hardcode the number of lines in the template to skip. DATAHERE is my only marker.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/DATAHERE/{r dataFile' -e 'd}' file
```

Focus on the line `DATAHERE` and read the file `dataFile` then delete the current line.

Comment: `sed -e '/DATAHERE/r dataFile' -e '/DATAHERE/d' file` should work with any sed. Or `sed -e '/DATAHERE/{r dataFile<newline>d}' file`